# Get response data from jmeter to robotframework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

Please guide me whether is there any way to get the response data from jmeter to robotframework? I have integrated robotframework with jmeter and my use case is to do the data base validation using robotframework for that i want to get the unique id which i recieved in jmeter responce data.Due to some use case i cannot perform Database validation in jmeter itself.

I Dont see any keyword in the documentation,
https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/JMeterLib.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the plugin offers such functionality so the most straightforward way is writing your unique id into a file, depending on how you're getting the ID you can:

1. Use [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener - it stores the whole response into a separate file
2. Use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property - it adds specified [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)(s) values as a separate column(s) in the .jtl results file
3. Use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) listener where you have the full freedom to choose regarding what, where and how to store

Once done you can read the file using [OperatingSystem library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20File) and do whatever you need with this ID